# Store values using dictionary approach

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns A and B. Column A has values (1,1,2,1,5,2) and Column B has values (A,B,C,D,E,F)
Created the following code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim a(), v, dic As Dictionary, m As Long, i As Long, cnt As Long, c As Long
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To m
        If Not dic.Exists(Cells(i, "A").Value) Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve a(1 To 1, 1 To cnt)
            a(1, cnt) = Cells(i, "B").Value
            dic.Add Cells(i, "A").Value, cnt
        Else
            a(1, dic.Item(Cells(i, "A").Value)) = a(1, dic.Item(Cells(i, "A").Value)) & ", " & Cells(i, "B").Value
        End If
    Next i
    For c = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        v = Split(a(1, c), ", ")
        Cells(1, c + 2).Resize(UBound(v) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)
    Next c
End Sub
```

The code populates the results for each key in a column starting from C. In fact, the code is working but I need your reviews to refine the code and to learn from you absolutely.

Comment: Read namedworkbook|thisworkbook.namedsheet.Range("A2:B" & m) into an array. Redim `a` (1 To 1, 1 To iif(m=2,2,m-1))  outside loop. Populate by looping array not sheet. Be explicit with worksheet references. Declare `v` as () As String

Comment: what happens when `ubound v = -1` as no "," in `a(1, c)` ?

Comment: In fact, the code is for demonstrating the solution (But I don't think it is the best approach). Is there a better solution for doing that?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah. I misspoke. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything terribly wrong with your overall approach.

The obvious efficiency changes would be:

1. To read values into an array (inputArray)
2. Oversize/Max size your intermediate array (tempArray) to avoid ReDim Preserve during each loop as this makes a copy of the array each time
3. Use explicit typing

Low hanging fruit:

1. Avoid implicit ActiveSheet referencing
2. Use more descriptive naming
3. Re-use variables
4. Add some white space in to help others read the code (at least me anyway)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutValuesByKeyColumn()
    Dim columnMapping As Scripting.dictionary, targetSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set columnMapping = New Scripting.dictionary 'qualify with class
    
    With targetSheet
        
        Dim lastRow As Long
        
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        Dim inputArray() As Variant, tempArray() As Variant
        
        inputArray = .Range("A2:B" & lastRow).Value
        
        ReDim tempArray(1 To 1, 1 To IIf(lastRow = 2, 2, lastRow - 1)) 'max size array at start

        Dim i As Long, counter As Long
        
        For i = LBound(inputArray, 1) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        
            If Not columnMapping.Exists(inputArray(i, 1)) Then
            
                counter = counter + 1
                tempArray(1, counter) = inputArray(i, 2)
                columnMapping.Add inputArray(i, 1), counter
                
            Else
            
                tempArray(1, columnMapping.Item(inputArray(i, 1))) = tempArray(1, columnMapping.Item(inputArray(i, 1))) & ", " & inputArray(i, 2)
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
        Dim columnValues() As String
       
        For i = 1 To UBound(tempArray, 2)
        
            If tempArray(1, i) <> vbNullString Then
                
                columnValues = Split(tempArray(1, i), ", ")
                .Cells(1, i + 2).Resize(UBound(columnValues, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(columnValues)
                
            Else
            
                .Cells(1, i + 2) = tempArray(1, i)
                
            End If
            
        Next
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Amazing and awesome.

Answer (score 1):

### Dictionary feat. Array List

- This is a different approach not touching the worksheet after reading the ranges into arrays and before writing the result.
- I tried it for a million rows, it took less than 80 seconds, while your solution took 240. You are accessing the worksheet and redim-preserving a lot. But you know this already.
- It surely can be improved since I just 'hacked away' and ran out of time.

**The Code**

```
Sub testWhat()
Dim dTime As Double
dTime = Timer
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirst As String = "A1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "C1"
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Range(sFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst)
    sadTest srg, drg
Debug.Print Timer - dTime
End Sub

Sub sadTest(sCell As Range, dcell As Range)
    Dim rg As Range
    With sCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg = .Columns(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    Dim kData As Variant: kData = rg.Value
    Dim vData As Variant: vData = rg.Offset(, 1).Value
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(kData, 1)
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = 1
    Dim rData As Variant: ReDim rData(1 To srCount)
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim dCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To srCount
        Key = kData(i, 1)
        If dict.Exists(Key) Then
            dCount = dict(Key) + 1
            rData(i) = dCount
            dict(Key) = dCount
            If dCount > drCount Then
                drCount = drCount + 1
            End If
        Else
            arl.Add Key
            dict(Key) = 1
            rData(i) = 1
        End If
    Next i
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = dict.Count
    
    ' arl.IndexOf(kData(i, 1), 0) + 1
    ' Application.Match(kData(i, 1), dict.keys, 0) ' to slow
    
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount)
    For i = 1 To srCount
        Result(rData(i), arl.IndexOf(kData(i, 1), 0) + 1) = vData(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    dcell.Resize(drCount, dcCount).Value = Result
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is amazing too.